# Laravel forge replacing seccond site

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

I am using laravel forge and it's awesome. However i ran into one problem.

I created a server on digital ocean and referred my domains to that ip. Everything good and well so far.
Than i created a site. Used the deployer and yup everything worked like a charm, however now i added a second site to the server. and well yes it added the site. so /home/forge/website2.com. However now when going to my previous site: website1.com it shows me website2.com.. i rebooted the server, reloaded nginx nothing seems to work als in sites_available the paths look good.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

Are site 1 and site 2 on different domains, or are they just different sub domains?

Have you tried comparing the Nginx configuration (you can get to it from the Forge site) between the two websites?

To me it seems that your Nginx configuration is wrong. Lastly, are either of them stored on the "default" site on forge or did you qualify a url and keep "default" empty?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved by taylor, He updated forge  and this isn't a problem anymore.